# How to return a div using jQuery in a DataTable child row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a problem when returning a div using jQuery. The attached code below works only until the first display of childRow content, unfortunately not later. This is probably due to returning an item with the same ID, does anyone have an idea how else to return this div?

**Script**

```
function format () {
    return $('#myDiv');
}

(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
       // table settings
    } );

    $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            row.child.hide();
        }
        else {
            row.child( format() ).show();
        }
    } );
} );
```

**myDiv**

```
div(id="myDiv" class="container"){
//some images
//some java bean references
}
```

Comment: By "child row", do you mean something like [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)? If so, can you use/adapt that "show/hide" approach here?

Comment: Just something like that. But because of the need to extract data from java beans, I wanted to do it in a separate div and call it after click row. Currently, the show/hide methods work, but only until the first click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by changing the Javascript library files, according to the  [example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/column-control.html)